# How can I join twice the same meta_key in a wp_query?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to do a wp_query and sort the results by these rules:

- normal post
- then by occurance of 'reseau = 48' => is_tontouta
- then by occurance of 'reseau = 171' => is_deroulant

The expected result is to have everypost not tontouta nor deroulant showing, then deroulant, then tontouta.

The issue is that the generated request by wp_query is joining twice the same table with the same alias:

```
    OR 
    ( mt1.meta_key = 'reseau_cf' AND mt1.meta_value = '48' ) 
    OR 
    ( mt1.meta_key = 'reseau_cf' AND mt1.meta_value = '171' )
```

I would like the second join to be (but maybe this is not the proper way):

```
( mt2.meta_key = 'reseau_cf' AND mt2.meta_value = '171' )
```

Here's the actual query (simplified for question purpose):

```
      'post_type'       => 'panneaux',
      'post_status'     => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page'  => -1,
      'meta_query'      => [
        'relation'  => 'AND',
        [
            'relation'  => 'OR',
            [
              'key'     => 'quartier',
              'compare' => 'exists',
            ],                              
            'is_tontouta'  => [
                'key'     => 'reseau',
                'compare' => '=',
                'value'   => 48,
            ],
            'is_deroulant'  => [
                'key'     => 'reseau',
                'compare' => '=',
                'value'   => 171,
            ],
        ],
        [
          'key'   => 'actif',
          'value' => 1,
        ],
      ],     
      'orderby'         => [
        'is_deroulant'  => 'DSC',
        'is_tontouta'   => 'DSC',
      ],
```

In this scenario, I cannot use a custom query as we are using WP grid Builder plugin and we need to use a WP_Query to work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out how Wordpress was creating his aliases for tables.

It uses a function 'find_compatible_table_alias' and fortunatly as a filter 'meta_query_find_compatible_table_alias'.

So if you overrule this filter, no same alias will be use and the joint will be different.

Just had this filter somewhere and it will work (but slow down queries be aware):

```
function no_alias_filter ($alias) {
  return false;
}
add_filter('meta_query_find_compatible_table_alias', 'no_alias_filter');
```